# How to change date format on zooming

Tags: zedgraph

Am using a ZedGraph in which data is plotted for a period of more than
one year. When its initially displayed, its showing the data in a
single shot but the X-axis is in DateTime format.  How can I set the X
axis values to Year at the time of loading?  I need to change the
format on different zooming levels ie, on further zooming the format
should be MMM/yyyy followed by DD/MMM/yyyy and DD/MMM/yyyy HH:MM:ss

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Before loading your data your should set something like:

```cs
zedgraphControl.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.Format = "dd.MM.yyyy";
```

And in `zedgraphControl_ZoomEvent` you can change scale format again like

```cs
private void zedgraphControl_ZoomEvent(ZedGraphControl sender, ZoomState oldState, ZoomState newState)
    {
        GraphPane pane = sender.GraphPane;
        pane.XAxis.Scale.Format = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss";
    }
```

In this event you can add some conditions depends on your current scale.

Comment: To run a test on your current scale, check the value of `yourGraph.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorUnit`